# AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf, debugging, web-services

I have a WCF Web application that uses a WCF Class Library.
My project is a WCF Web project and I am self-hosting.

My problem is that all my web service methods hang with:

And "Unable to automatically step into the server...etc".

The error (not very helpful) returned is:

```
The operation has timed out
```

When I invoke the same method(s) using the WCF Test Client 
I get the correct response and everything goes smoothly.

So, something must be wrong with my web application.

Following up on a similar post, I used the Service Trace Viewer.
I am getting the error:

```
The message with To 
'http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/Authentication/mex/mex' 
cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the 
EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses 
agree.
```

After reading a related post, I tried adding:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
```

And recompiling my class library and updating my services to no avail... still hangs.

I have tried adding both my web service and my web project as startup projects but 
I am still unable to step into the code. I also have all the appropriate DEBUG attributes
set in Web.config and App.config.

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without knowing what your configuration looks like, it's hard to say what's wrong. However, why does your URL have /mex twice in it? Are you sure that's right?

Comment: yeah, that looked wrong to me too and I was hoping it was the answer but when I look at my web config i don't see that - in fact, i only see: 

'http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/Authentication

Comment: The service configuration seems alright to me, but about the mex address, I was really referring to your client, which seems to be using the wrong address.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I posted all my CONFIG files below. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but from what I can see in the config files, I see that the URL you're using in your client config for the services is not the same one that you're getting an error for on the server (nor does it match the base address prefixes you registered on the server side). Are you sure you're looking at the right configurations?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  The /mex/mex also shows up in my trace log, but I don't see it anywhere in the config.  What was the solution?

Comment: This is marked as a solution, but there is no actual answer here. I'm having the same problem, @Code how did you actually fix this?

Comment: @IronicMuffin I agree with you I am having the same issue, but there is no answer here. Did you finally solve it?

Comment: @Joze I've gotten past it, but honestly I couldn't tell you how. I rebuilt various bits in IIS, restarted app pools, ensured everything server side was correct. Also tried re-added the service reference to visual studio. At some point, the damn thing just started working again. Haven't had the problem since.

Comment: @IronicMuffin - At least for me, the solution was to double check that endpoint in client config and baseAddress in server config match exactly. E.g. `<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/ServiceName/EndpointName" ... />` <==> `<add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/ServiceName/EndpointName" />`.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the mex/mex error occurs when I update a service reference in Visual Studio.  I have come to the conclusion that this is just part of how Visual Studio figures out how to update the web service rere